# Get a package configuration file as an array

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, command-line-interface

When I write:

```
$config->get('database');
```

... I get the whole content of `app/config/database.php`. How to do the same thing to configuration files belonging to packages?

(The contents of `app/config/packages/vendor/package/somefile.php`).

**Note:** I am using a CLI environment where I'm loading the framework manually.

```
// composer (Laravel) bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap/autoload.php';

/* @var $app \Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
$app = require_once 'bootstrap/start.php';

$config = $app->make('config');

print_r($config->get('my-package::config'));
```

Comment: You may want to consider creating an artisan command and executing that from the command line.  That way your logic will run within your fully configured Laravel application.

Comment: @patricus Thanks, but that is unfortunately not a possibility. I'm not executing my file directly, it runs as part of an other tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Laravel 4 package configuration is accessed by it's *package namespace*. That's usually the package name itself:

```
$config->get('package::somefile');
```

Since apparently the config namespace isn't accessible without doing `$app->run()` you could load the config file manually. It's not the prettiest solution but will do the job:

```
$packageConfig = require app_path('config/packages/vendor/package/somefile.php');
```

Comment: It works on the live site, but does not in CLI mode. Please see the edit I made to the question.

Comment: Hmm. I don't know why that could be. Is the CLI environment using the exact same application files as the live site?

Comment: Yes. Everything is the same. If I do an `$app->run()` (exactly what index.php does), the config is accessible afterwards. The problem with this is that run() does many other things (like trying to write the log and failing because of permissions).

Comment: I see. To be honest I have no idea why the package config is only loaded after `$app->run()` but see my updated answer for a workaround.

Comment: I can not find `config_path` defined anywhere in the code base.

Comment: Sorry I forgot that `config_path` only exists in Laravel 5. You can use `app_path('config/...')`. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the framework (at least the interesting parts) by running:

```
$app->boot();
```

After this step the *Config repository* properly is initialized. So the proper way to set up a minimal CLI environment (without running the app) is:

```
// composer (Laravel) bootstrap
require_once 'bootstrap/autoload.php';

/* @var $app \Illuminate\Foundation\Application */
$app = require_once 'bootstrap/start.php';
$app->boot();
```

after this the package configuration files are accessible through the usual way:

```
$config = $app->make('config');

print_r($config->get('my-package::config'));
```